# Your access to TinyMCE will expire on 25 Februrary 2021 ! How to fix it?

Tags: tinymce

I'm using https://geodesicsolutions.com/ platform for my website.  Their support is stopped for everyone.

However, when I try to edit the description text of my listing, I see this message: "Your access to TinyMCE will expire on 25 Februrary 2021. Please either contact your administrator or upgrade your account using the instructions available here."

How Can I fix it?

Thanks. Eyad

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about customer support.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that if you follow the link that is tied to the word "here" at the end of that error message it will take you to a blog post outlining the issue and how you can fix it.

The slightly longer answer is that the software you are using points to a free CDN that we are retiring on 25-Feb-2021 after which TinyMCE won't be delivered from that CDN.

We have a few blog posts on what we are doing around consolidating our CDNs:

- https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/announcement-decommissioning-cdn-tinymce-com/
- https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/reminder-decommissioning-tinymce-cachefly-cdn